# How do I automatically add a title to imported entities?

Tags: feeds, 9

I have a site with a lot of audio files (using core's **Media audio** media type).

On the **Manage form display** admin page (`/admin/structure/media/manage/audio/form-fields`), I have set the **Name** field to **Disabled**.

This way, when I add a media audio entity in the UI (at `/media/add/audio`), then I don't have to add the title, and the entity name will automatically be set to the file name.

Now I want to automate media audio entity creation with the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/).  I configured a feed type + a feed for my media audio entities.  I'm importing CSV files from a directory.

I used the following mappings:

- File ID + File Description for the media field `field_media_audio_file`
- Code for the text field `field_import_id` (for which I set the *unique* option to keep track of imports)

However, when I try to import the feed, I get this error:

> Name (name): This value should not be null.

How can I disable this validation (checking for the Name field) by the Feeds module for media audio entities?

As a workaround, I can create a column in the CSV file and list all the file names, but this results in duplicate information and presents the risk of typos.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to assign a default Name?

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a more elegant way to do this, but for now I decided to patch the validator itself in `/feeds/src/Feeds/Processor/EntityProcessorBase.php`:

```
if ($label || $label === '0' || $label === 0) {
  $messages[] = $this->t('The @entity %label failed to validate with the following errors: @errors', $args);
  if (mb_strtolower($this->entityTypeLabel()) === 'media') {
    // Media will automatically have the title set to filename, so allow this.
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: `mb_strtolower($this->entityTypeLabel()) === 'media'` - this is strange to me. Surely you can just get the entity type's machine name. E.g., `$this->entityTypeId()`

Comment: @sonfd Yeah, it seemed weird to me, too.  But that's how the Feeds module itself is doing it in the code immediately above, so I decided to stick with the same code as the module itself.

Answer (score 0):

Feeds has `presave` and `prevalidate` events.  So another way to approach this is to add an [event subscriber (sample code from the maintainer](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/2991955#comment-13197693)).

In this case, validation can be overridden with `PROCESS_ENTITY_PREVALIDATE`.